# Shuffle character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, shuffle

I have to solve the following problem:

The following incomplete code illustrates a program that consists of an array holding 16 sorted names. The last part of the program displays these names on the screen. You are required to write code in the part which is being marked with an empty rectangle so that the names will be shuffled. When the names are outputted they should not be outputted in ascending order but in a random order. You are only required to write in you examination script the missing code and not the entire program.

How can I write this code in the most simple/intuitive way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    char temp[20];
    char names[16][20] = { "Anne" , "Carmen" , "David" , "Jesmond" ,
    "John" , "Joseph" , "Karen" , "Kevin" ,
    "Manuel" , "Maria" , "Matthew" , "Michaela" ,
    "Paul" , "Sandra" , "William" , "Yilenia" };

    //--------------------------- The Code between the dotted lines is the one I still need to write -----------------
    char randomnames[16][20];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        j = rand() % 17;
        printf("%d\n", j);
        randomnames[i] = names[j];
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        puts(randomnames[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a really interesting problem. Do you have a question, though?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As a hint, read the time and use it to seed a pseudo random number generator. Since you cannot include any extra header files, and using an external declarations to C standard library functions is probably considered cheating, you could implement your own PRNG using a linear congruential generator. That's a lot easier than it sounds.

Comment: Some problems with your code are: (1) you cannot assign array elements that are themselves arrays; (2) it does not shuffle - you could get duplicate values in the resulting array; (3) you generate random numbers from 0 to 16, but 16 is out of range for your array. To solve (1), use a loop to copy the array elements (assuming you cannot `#include <string.h>` and use `memcpy` or `strncpy`). To solve (2), investigate the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
char names[16][20] = ...;
char randomnames[16][20];
```

you cannot do

```
randomnames[i] = names[j];
```

but

```
char names[16][20] = ...;
char * randomnames[16];
...
randomnames[i] = names[j];
```

or

```
char names[16][20] = ...;
char randomnames[16][20];
...
strcpy(randomnames[i], names[j]);
```

---

Warning when I see your first version of the question you have to print *names* rather than *randomnames*, that means you need to modify *randomnames* and the `char temp[20]` clearly indicates you have to swap the names inside *randomnames*

So something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, j, k;
  char temp[20];
  char names[16][20] = { "Anne" , "Carmen" , "David" , "Jesmond" ,
                         "John" , "Joseph" , "Karen" , "Kevin" ,
                         "Manuel" , "Maria" , "Matthew" , "Michaela" ,
                         "Paul" , "Sandra" , "William" , "Yilenia" };

  //--------------------------- The Code between the dotted lines is the one I still need to write -----------------
  srand(time(NULL));

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) /* can be an other number of loop */
  {
    j = rand() % 17;
    k = rand() % 17;
    if (j != k) {
      strcpy(temp, names[j]);
      strcpy(names[j], names[k]);
      strcpy(names[k], temp);
    }
  }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    puts(names[i]);
  }
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

As you see I use all the variables and no additional ones.

Example of compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc -pedantic -Wall s.c
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./a.out
Sandra
John
William
Karen
Joseph
Kevin
Manuel
Carmen
Anne
Jesmond
Michaela
Maria
Paul
Matthew
David
Yilenia
```

Comment: Thanks. Strcpy might be the way?

Comment: tnx that's a helpful tip

Comment: With the code you have both are ok, the vector ([]) uses less memory that the array ([][]) because the strings are still unique rather than duplicated, after all depends if you want after to modify or the string stored in _randomnames_ but not _names_, if yes you need the array and the _strcpy_

Comment: @denederlander looking at the link you given first your way is not the expected one, I edited my answer

Comment: @denederlander **no** you redo the initial error, `temp = names[j];` is wrong, follow my code

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful :)